How can I determine whether requests to my web server are coming from hosts directly connected to the switch or from neighboring switches?
I have a Linux host connected to a layer 2 switch where I’ve set up a web server using Laravel. On this web server, I need to identify the source of incoming requests: whether the requester is directly connected to the switch or accessing it through neighboring switches.
This differentiation is important because I need to implement distinct security policies for these two zones. I plan to configure two IP ranges on my Linux host—one for local access and another for remote access—so that I can identify the request sources based on their IP addresses.
I want the switch to permit requests from the local IP range through a specific port while blocking all other ports from sending requests with local-range IPs. if requests come from other ports, should be from remote-range IPs.
how could I resolve these zones by any mechanism?

There's no way to tell what switch is involved at layer-2.

Layer-2 switches are transparent devices.

@RonMaupin vlan cant helps me for managing accesses?

Possibly, but we have no information on you network devices. Your hosts/servers are off-topic here, but you would need a trunk between the server and the switch for different VLANs, and you switches must support VLANs. We do not have enough information to help.

@RonMaupin i have a dlink dgs3000 switch, it is layer 2 and managed, my webserver is a ARM linux.

Unfortunately, those devices are off-topic here. Please take the [tour] and read the What topics can I ask about here? page.


On this web server, I need to identify the source of incoming requests: whether the requester is directly connected to the switch or accessing it through neighboring switches.

The web server cannot make that distinction. A managed switch could  - it would allow you to look up the port the source MAC address is associated with. On an unmanaged switch there is no way.
Of course, you could also use the source MAC or IP address to identify the host on the web server.

I need to implement distinct security policies for these two zones

Setting up different security zones within an IP subnet doesn't work well. Instead, you use VLANs to separate L2 traffic into different subnets and then control traffic on the gateway between them - either a firewall or a switch with ACLs.

I want the switch to permit requests from the local IP range through a specific port while blocking all other ports from sending requests with local-range IPs.

If you set up L3 ACLs on a switch within a single network segment/IP subnet/VLAN, then you need to make sure that the filtered hosts don't change their IP addresses arbitrarily. You could set up static MAC-to-IP settings or force them to use DHCP and configure DHCP snooping. Again, it's much better to filter between VLANs/IP subnets.

The web server can't see anything about layer-2. It's only looking at layer-3 information. (i.e. a TCP/IP socket.)

@Zac67 i have a dlink dgs3000 switch, it is layer 2 and managed, my webserver is a ARM linux. how firewall or ACL could help me?

As described above: set up different VLANs and routing between them (you'd need an additional router/L3 switch with filtering features). Sorry, host configurations are explicitly off topic here, and for a device to be on topic here the vendor needs to offer optional, paid support, see the [help/on-topic].
